# Page Route Animations Triggering initState Loop Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am having trouble understanding custom page route animations in flutter. I am trying to navigate from a router screen to one of a few screens depending on whether or not the user is still logged in when opening the app.

```
class RouterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<RouterPage> createState() => _RouterPageState();
}

class _RouterPageState extends State<RouterPage> {
  StreamSubscription? subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => subscription =
            FirebaseAuth.instance
                .authStateChanges()
                .listen((firebaseUser) async {
          if (firebaseUser != null) {
            try {
              await DBService.retrieveUser(firebaseUser.uid);
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .pushReplacement(FadeRoute(page: HomePageScreen()));
            } catch (e) {
              if (e.toString() == ErrorTypes.noUserError.toString()) {
                print("Logged in no db entry");
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MyCustomPageRoute(
                        parent: widget,
                        builder: (context) => LoginPageScreen()));
              }
            }
          } else {
            print("Not logged in");
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context,
                MyCustomPageRoute(
                    parent: widget, builder: (context) => LoginPageScreen()));
          }
        }));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    if (subscription != null) {
      subscription!.cancel();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProgressWheel();
  }
```

I also have a custom page route in which I define the transition that I want to take place:

```
class MyCustomPageRoute<T> extends MaterialPageRoute<T> {
  final Widget parent;

  MyCustomPageRoute({
    required this.parent,
    required WidgetBuilder builder,
    RouteSettings? settings,
  }) : super(builder: builder, settings: settings);

  @override
  Widget buildTransitions(_, Animation<double> animation, __, Widget child) {
    var anim1 = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset.zero, end: Offset(-1.0, 0.0))
        .animate(animation);
    var anim2 = Tween<Offset>(begin: Offset(1.0, 0.0), end: Offset.zero)
        .animate(animation);
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        SlideTransition(position: anim1, child: parent),
        SlideTransition(position: anim2, child: child),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

When I open the app and I am not logged in, I correctly hit the "MyCustomPageRoute". However, the transition occurs on a loop, constantly creating new instances of the LoginScreenPage() to which I am navigating. Is there a better way I should be going about this?

Interestingly, I do not get this looping behavior when I use this FadeRoute instead of the MyCustomPageRoute

```
class FadeRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;
  FadeRoute({required this.page})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
          ) =>
              page,
          transitionsBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            Animation<double> animation,
            Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
            Widget child,
          ) =>
              FadeTransition(
            opacity: animation,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
}
```